# How can I see the Action Bar in Eclipse when developing for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am wondering if it is possible to preview the Action Bar in the Android Graphical Layout while looking at an Activity?

Comment: Hmm, also looking for this. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded an SDK where the ActionBar is included (e.g. API 14 or 15), you can change the version of Android that the Graphical Layout uses to render the layout in Eclipse.

In the top row of the window, you can select 'Locale', 'Android version' as well as create a new layout. Set Android Version to API 14 or above (Android 4.0 or above) and you should be able to see the ActionBar. Also set the Theme below to a suitable 'Theme.Holo.*'

Comment: This does not work to show the actionbar because the actionbar is not in the same xml as the layout. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check which API version you are targeting (in the manifest). I normally use 14 or above. Also do you use ActionBarSherlock or the native ActionBar?